# Listview not displaying response from retrofit api call

Tags: android, listview, retrofit

I made a retrofit call in android and got a list response objects back but for some reason, they are not getting displayed in the `listview` and the application is not crashing either.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OpenNotifyService mService;
    ListView listView ;

    List<Response> arrayList = new ArrayList<Response>();
    ArrayAdapter<Response> adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mService = ApiUtils.getOpenNotifyService();

            // Get ListView object from xml
            listView =  findViewById(R.id.myListView);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Response>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);

            loadAnswers();

        }

    public void loadAnswers() {
        mService.getTimes(12,10).enqueue(new Callback<InternationalSpaceStationPassTimes>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<InternationalSpaceStationPassTimes> call, retrofit2.Response<InternationalSpaceStationPassTimes> response) {
                Log.e("Request URL", call.request().url().toString());
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    arrayList= response.body().getResponse();

// Assign adapter to ListView

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            int itemPosition     = position;

                            // ListView Clicked item value
                            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                            // Show Alert
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    // handle request errors depending on status code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<InternationalSpaceStationPassTimes> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me..

Comment: Put `adapter` initialisation  inside `onResponse` just below `arrayList` because `adapter` is created with empty `arrayList`

Comment: You might want to put the `setOnItemClickListener` code inside the `onCreate` method

Answer (score 1):

Your list is initialized when your Activity instance is constructed:

> ```
> List<Response> arrayList = new ArrayList<Response>();
> ```

During `onCreate()`, your adapter is constructed:

> ```
> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Response>(this, 
>                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
>                   android.R.id.text1,
>                   arrayList);
> ```

Inside your `loadAnswers()` callback, your list is **reinitialized**:

> ```
> arrayList= response.body().getResponse();
> ```

Finally, you attach the adapter to the listview:

> ```
> listView.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

Your problem is that your callback assigns a different `List` instance to your `arrayList` variable. Since your adapter was already created at this point, this means that the list inside of `adapter` is different from the list pointed to by `arrayList`. So nothing will appear.

You can solve this a couple of different ways. Probably the easiest would be to change your `loadAnswers()` callback to do this instead:

```
arrayList.clear();
arrayList.addAll(response.body().getResponse());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```